# Rails - Shared entry between 2 Users - Soft deletion for each user independently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, soft-delete, ruby-paranoia

I have a Rails 5 app with 2 models : `User` & `Application`
User can apply to another User through Application model

When an Application is created by User 1 to User 2, both users can see it inside their `Application#index` view.

Each User can delete an application, but that must not impact the visibility for the second user involved.

Example :

- User 1 apply to User 2
- User 1 and User 2 have the application inside `Application#index` view
- User 1 soft delete application
- User 1 do not see the application in `Application#index`
- User 2 still see the application in `Application#index`

What is the most correct way to deal with this situation ?

- Create 2 column `sender_deleted` & `receiver_deleted` and fill them accordinately with date + `scope {sender_deleted: nil }` for index
- Create an entry for each user in Application then retrieve only the ones for each user ?
- Other way ?

The second way seems proper, but the only info that differs in the table is the deletion date so it seems a little redundant.

Please note that I use the Paranoia gem for regular soft delete in my other models, not possible here with the 1 solution but possible with the second as only one column will be necessary to define the user as deleted.